# SWITCH_SELECTION, CalculateAreas_stats and ARE_IDENTICAL_TO not behaving as they should be in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I want to select features by location using "Are identical to" method and then want to switch the selection so that I have only the features that have been edited or newly created. Then I'll select features with some particular attributes and add them to a layer so that user can check them later.

Second process in this script is to execute the area statistics and add this layer to the table of content for the convenience of user.

However when I run this script, line no 1 and 2 executes with no error but doesn't make any selection and the line no 3 executes like it is a new selection. Line no 4 never runs and stopped with error as "cannot execute CalculateAreas_stats()".

I am not able to figure out why it is doing so and looking for some insights for this problem.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import pythonaddins
import os
from os import path
import glob

class ButtonQC(object):
    """Implementation for Tool_twoDCM_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        namD = ("Invalid Remark", "Check Area")
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        Lyrlst = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        aDF = mxd.activeDataFrame
        z = 0
        i = 1
        conflict = ""
        prod = ""
        source = ""
        desc = arcpy.Describe(Lyrlst[1])
        outDir = str(desc.path) + "\\Error_Layer_output_" + str(i)
        while os.path.isdir(outDir):
            i+=1
            outDir = str(desc.path) + "\\Error_Layer_output_" + str(i)
            if not os.path.isdir(outDir):
                os.mkdir(outDir)
                break
        else:
            os.mkdir(outDir)

        for lyr in Lyrlst:
            Fld_lst = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(lyr)]
            if len(Fld_lst) < 5:
                conflict = lyr
                print(lyr.name + "= extent")
                if z == 0:
                    z = 1
                elif z == 1:
                    z = 2
                elif z == 2:
                    z = 3
            elif "Remark" in Fld_lst and len(Fld_lst) > 9:
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", '"Remark" <> ' + "''")
                Num = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr).getOutput(0))
                if Num > 0:
                    prod = lyr
                    print(lyr.name + "= prod")
                    lyr.definitionQuery = '"Remark" <> ' + "'D'"
                    if z == 0:
                        z = 1
                    elif z == 1:
                        z = 2
                    elif z == 2:
                        z = 3
                else:
                    source = lyr
                    print(lyr.name + "= source")
                    if z == 0:
                        z = 1
                    elif z == 1:
                        z = 2
                    elif z == 2:
                        z = 3
            elif not "Remark" in Fld_lst and len(Fld_lst) > 9:
                source = lyr
                print(lyr.name + "= source")
                if z == 0:
                    z = 1
                elif z == 1:
                    z = 2
                elif z == 2:
                    z = 3
        if z == 3:
            try:
                arcpy.env.workspace = outDir
                arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Invalid Remark in Edited Data 

                arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(prod, "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", source, "", "NEW_SELECTION")           # Line 1
                arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(prod, None, None, "", "SWITCH_SELECTION")           # Line 2
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(prod, "SUBSET_SELECTION", '"ID" <> ' + "' ' AND " + '"Remark" NOT IN (' + "'T', 'D', 'U', ' ', '')")           # Line 3
                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(prod, outDir, namD[0])
                ct1 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(namD[0])[0])
                if ct1 < 1:
                    try:
                        print("OK\n")
                        REMOVE = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(aDF, namD[0])[0]
                        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(aDF, REMOVE)
                    except Exception as d:
                        print(d.message)
                else:
                    print("Invalid Remark in Edited Data\n")
#Area

                arcpy.CalculateAreas_stats(prod, namD[1])           # Line 4
                ct2 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(namD[1])[0])
                if ct2 < 1:
                    try:
                        print("OK\n")
                        REMOVE = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(aDF, namD[1])[0]
                        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(aDF, REMOVE)
                    except Exception as d:
                        print(d.message)
                else:
                    print("Check Area\n")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e.message)
```